# Проблема с выделением памяти C++

Tags: c++, указатели, память

Существует следующий программа, которая объединяет две строки, предварительно выделив необходимое количество памяти. Здесь мы задаем строки, непосредственно,в самом коде. Но как быть, если их нужно, например, ввести с клавиатуры? Ведь их при этом нужно тоже записывать в какой-то массив, а для него нужно тоже выделять какое-то количество памяти, которое мы не знаем. Можно ли обойти данную проблему?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

char* giveNewMem(char *pstr1, int reqSize);

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    int strSize1 = strlen("строка 1 ") + 1;
    int strSize2 = strlen("+ строка 2") + 1;

    char* pStr1 = new char[strSize1];
    strcpy_s(pStr1, strSize1, "строка 1 ");

    char* pStr2 = new char[strSize2];
    strcpy_s(pStr2, strSize2, "+ строка 2");

    cout << "1)" << pStr1 << endl;
    cout << "2)" << pStr2 << endl << endl;

    cout << "pStr1 занимает " << strSize1 << " байт памяти c \\0" << endl;
    cout << "pStr2 занимает " << strSize2 << " байт памяти c \\0" << endl;

    // strcat_s(pStr1, strSize1, pStr2); // НЕПРАВИЛЬНО! НЕДОСТАТОЧНО ПАМЯТИ В pStr1

    int requiredSize = (strSize1 + strSize2) - 1;
    cout << "\nНеобходимо " << requiredSize << " байт памяти для объединения строк." << endl << endl;

    pStr1 = giveNewMem(pStr1, requiredSize); //функция, которая перевыделит память

    strcat_s(pStr1, requiredSize, pStr2);
    cout << "pStr1: " << pStr1 << endl << endl;

    delete[] pStr1; // освобождаем память, которая была перевыделена в функции для strInFunc 
    delete[] pStr2; // освобождаем память, которая была выделена в main 

    return 0;
}

char* giveNewMem(char *pstr1, int reqSize)
{
    char* strInFunc = new char[reqSize]; // для копирования строки pstr1 перед удалением памяти

    strcpy_s(strInFunc, reqSize, pstr1);

    delete [] pstr1; // освобождаем память pstr1

    return strInFunc;
}
```

Comment: Функций ввода много. Изучите сначало, какие бывают, т.к. в разных функциях эта проблема по-разному решена. Укажите с какой именно из функций ввода у вас возникла проблема.

Comment: Функция `getchar`, например - возвращает один символ, и не требует выделение ей памяти.

Comment: а может просто использовать std::string? и все решается?

Comment: @KoVadim функция strcpy_s не работает с string

Comment: @SlavaKotvitskiy: Ну так не используйте `strcpy*`, сдалась она вам?

Comment: конечно не работает, есть нормальная конкатенация

Comment: @KoVadim "нормальная" это какая ?

Comment: @vegorov ,  s = s1 + s2 ;  для строковых обьектов. Наверняка  KoVadim имел ввиду это

Comment: @ARHovsepyan понятно что он имел в виду, просто мог бы и написать, а не ссылаться на "нормальная конкатенация".

Comment: @VladD а что использовать? мне нужно в массивы `pStr1` и `pStr2` поместить содержимое строк, которые вводим из клавиатуры.
Просто присвоить тоже нельзя, если эти строки будут класса string, потому что массивы типа char*

Comment: @vegorov по моему, уж слишком очевидно, как конкатенировать (складывать) строки.  Просто ввести строку в std::string можно. Если вдруг (ну мало чего, у преподавателя полное незнание с++), нужен именно char*, всегда есть c_str().

Comment: Функции с суффиксом _s не являются частью страндарта С++ и пользоваться ими не стоит --

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не очень понел, чего хотите добиваться, но вот вам два варианта, как знать какого размера массив подготовить для получения данных из cin

### первый вариант:

```
cout << "введите перед строкой столько же произвольных символов, "
     <<"сколько в строке будет символов, разделяя их символом ';'\n";
//некоторые неудобства при вводе
int k = 0;
while((char)cin.peek() != ';') {
    cin.ignore();
    ++k;
    cin.clear();
}
cin.ignore(); // игнорируем ';'
// теперь знаем размер массива
char* pch = new char[k + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < k;  ++i)
    cin >> pch[i];
cout << pch;
```

### Второй вариант:

```
istream_iterator<string> is(cin);
auto It = is->begin();
int k = is->size();
char* pch = new char[k + 1];
for (int i = 0; i < k;  ++i) {
    pch[i] = *It;
    ++It;
}    
cout << pch;
```

Comment: если уже человеку хочется читать хитро, то может посмотреть на готовый  getline из glibc https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29576799/reading-an-unknown-length-line-from-stdin-in-c-with-fgets

Answer (score 0):

Классическое решение -- вводить порциями в буфер фиксированного размера, по заполнению которого делать realloc() результирующей строки и копировать буфер в хвост этой строки. Типа так:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <cerrno>

int eoi(int c);
const size_t buff_sz = 16;
char buff[buff_sz + 1]; // единицу здесь дописал, чтобы в отладчике не видеть мусор -- там всегда будет '\0'

void store_buff();
char *string = NULL;

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int i = 0;

    for (;;) {
        int c = getc(stdin);
        if (eoi(c)) {
            break;
        }
        buff[i++] = c;
        if (i == buff_sz) {
            store_buff();
            i = 0;
    }   }
    printf("%s\n", string);
    free(string);
    return(0);

}

int eoi(int c) {
    return (c == EOF ||
        //    c == '\n'||
            c == 'Z');
}

void store_buff() {

    static int string_sz = 0;
    string = (char *)realloc(string, string_sz + buff_sz);
    if (string == NULL) {
        perror("store_buff()");
        exit(errno);
    }
    strncpy(string + string_sz, buff, buff_sz);
    string_sz += buff_sz;

    return;
}
```